# Crash in libswiftCore.dylib _assertionFailed, no idea what is causing this

Tags: ios, realm

Ok, so I understand that this question is a bit broad, but I do not know how to proceed.

So this is what my crash looks like from fabric (I have not been able to reproduce this, but I'm getting alot of crashes like this)

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libswiftCore.dylib             0x101085cb8 _assertionFailed(StaticString, String, StaticString, UInt, flags : UInt32) -> Never (__hidden#16085_:167)
1  libswiftCore.dylib             0x1010a5a70 _hidden#1062_ + 504
2  libswiftCore.dylib             0x1010a5878 swift_errorInMain + 26
3  MYAPPPPPP                      0x10006da44 specialized static FFBaseApiService.accessTokenGetString.getter (FFBaseApiService.swift)
4  libdispatch.dylib              0x191a9a1bc _dispatch_client_callout + 16
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x191a9afb0 dispatch_once_f + 56
6  MYAPPPPPP                      0x100105208 specialized FFAppDelegate.application(UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions : [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]?) -> Bool (FFAppDelegate.swift:62)
7  MYAPPPPPP                      0x100101b70 @objc FFAppDelegate.application(UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions : [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]?) -> Bool (FFAppDelegate.swift)
8  UIKit                          0x198b386a4 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 400
9  UIKit                          0x198d48a98 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 3524
10 UIKit                          0x198d4e808 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1656
11 UIKit                          0x198d63104 __84-[UIApplication _handleApplicationActivationWithScene:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.3139 + 48
12 UIKit                          0x198d4b7ec -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 168
13 FrontBoardServices             0x1947e792c __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 36
14 FrontBoardServices             0x1947e7798 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 176
15 FrontBoardServices             0x1947e7b40 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 56
16 CoreFoundation                 0x192bbeb5c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
17 CoreFoundation                 0x192bbe4a4 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 524
18 CoreFoundation                 0x192bbc0a4 __CFRunLoopRun + 804
19 CoreFoundation                 0x192aea2b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
20 UIKit                          0x198b317b0 -[UIApplication _run] + 608
21 UIKit                          0x198b2c534 UIApplicationMain + 208
22 MYAPPPPPP                      0x100059138 main (UserDefaultsWrapper.swift:21)
23 libdispatch.dylib              0x191acd5b8 (Missing)
```

To me it seems as if it's this row that is crashing on appdelegate startup:

```
specialized static FFBaseApiService.accessTokenGetString.getter (FFBaseApiService.swift)
```

This is the code for this:

```
class var accessTokenGetString : String {
    return "?accessToken=\(currentUserAccessToken)"
}

class var currentUserAccessToken : String {
    return FFUserManager.sharedInstance.getUserAccessToken()
}
```

Also, I am using realm, and the getUserAccessToken looks like this:

```
func getUserAccessToken() -> String {
        if let user = user, let accessToken = user.accessToken {
            return accessToken
        }
        else {
            print("Returning empty access token")
            return ""
        }

    }
```

Where the user property is fetched like this:

```
private var user : FFUser? {
    return realm.objects(FFUser.self).first
}
```

I have NO IDEA whatsoever what could be wrong here. Any takers?

Comment: How are you creating the `realm` inside your `user` getter? If you are using `try!` and a Swift error is thrown, you might get a stacktrace like the one you're seeing. You might want to try wrapping it in a do-catch block and logging/`fatalError()`ing the error upon failure.

Comment: @AustinZ I will try this, thank you. I am indeed using a try!